# Python while loop neither works nor breaks

Tags: python, while-loop

My code and the output is as below.
I expected loop but it doesn't work and it doesn't break either. Still running.
Can someone fix the code and teach why it doesn't loop ?
I know I can make it loop if I use `for` instead `while`. But I want to know why.

code:

```
absent = [2,5]  
student = 1
while student < 11:
    if student in absent :
        continue
    print(f"student {student} is attended!")
    student += 1
```

output:

```
student 1 is attended!
```

Comment: Instead of saying "Thank you", Please consider accepting one the answers if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure it is because of the `continue` and absent of the `break`. It gets stuck in an infinite loop.
You could do it like this:

```py
absent = [2,5]  
student = 1
while student < 11:
    if student not in absent:
        print(f"student {student} is attended!")
    student += 1
```

Here some info about the `continue` and `break` in a loop: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/break-continue

Answer (score 1):

when `student` is `1`，do：

```py
    print(f"student {student} is attended!")
    student += 1
```

but when `student` is `2`, if-statement is `True`, `continue` works and passes:

```py
    print(f"student {student} is attended!")
    student += 1"
```

and  3,4,5..10 don't go on.

Answer (score 0):

Your code runs infinite times because at first iteration if condition fails and prints the output and increments the `student`.

In second iteration if condition will be true then it continues(which skips all the statements below the `continue` statement and moves to the loop) so that your student will be always `2`.

try this:

```py
absent = [2, 5]
student = 1
while student < 11:
    if student in absent:
        student += 1

    else:
        print(f"student {student} is attended!")
        student += 1
```